# QueriesTableAdapter CommandTimeout

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a QueriesTableAdapter with an Update stored procedure that takes a long time to execute. I am trying to increase the command timeout property of the Queries Table Adapter from which the stored procedure is called.

The stored proc is a maintainance routine that is called infrequently by one process via a webservice.

Please note: it is a QueriesTableAdapter and not a TableAdapter and I am using .net 4.5 VS 2012

In the code behind in my DAL I added the following:

```
Namespace mbr_AccountTableAdapters
    Partial Public Class QueriesTableAdapter

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Sets the commant timeout.
        ''' Set to 0 to specify the longest timout value supported by the db.
        ''' </summary>
        Public WriteOnly Property CommandTimeout As Integer
            Set(value As Integer)
                If Not IsNothing(Me._commandCollection) Then
                    For Each cmd As System.Data.IDbCommand In Me._commandCollection
                        cmd.CommandTimeout = value
                    Next
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
End Namespace
```

I can then run my stored procedure using the following code from my BLL:

```
Dim rows As Integer = 0 'number of affected rows

Using myQTA As New DAL.mbr_AccountTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter

    'increase the command timeout:
    myQTA.CommandTimeout = 0 '0 = larget value possible

    Dim queryResult As Object
    queryResult = myQTA.usrsp_mbr_account_CleanupInactive()
    If Not IsNothing(queryResult) Then
        rows = Convert.ToInt32(queryResult)
    End If

End Using
```

---

I am getting the following error:

[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]

---

Please note, the query works - there are no problems with the connection or any other errors. If I reduce the amount of data that needs processing to a tiny subset of data, the query runs without errors.

The problem is when it takes longer than 30 seconds.

**The query times out exactly after 30 seconds.**

Adding 'Connection Timeout=90' to the database connection string in the web.config makes no difference, it still times out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.

The _commandCollection is always NULL and therefore the CommandTimeout value is never set.

We must call InitCommandCollection() first to initialize the command collection, then we are able to set the CommandTimeout value:

I changed my code to:

```
Public WriteOnly Property CommandTimeout As Integer
    Set(value As Integer)

        'initialize the collection first:
        If IsNothing(Me._commandCollection) Then
            Me.InitCommandCollection()
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(Me._commandCollection) Then
            For Each cmd As System.Data.IDbCommand In Me._commandCollection
                cmd.CommandTimeout = value
            Next
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

It is now working as expected and I can set a custom timeout value for the stored procedure.

I hope this information helps somebody else.